# AJAX jQuery & PHP issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I'm looking is that when the button is clicked then the values are taken and put into variables. The variables are then used in the AJAX call, so I can post them.

```
function addTask(){
  $("#add_task_button").click(function(){
    var task_title = $('#add_task_title').val();
    var task_description = $('#add_task_desc').val();
    var task_member = $( "#task_member option:selected" ).text();
    var task_status = $( "#task_status option:selected" ).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: '../php_scripts/add_task.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'title': task_title, 'description': task_description, 'member': task_member, 'status': task_status},
        success: function() {
          alert("SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
          alert("FAILURE");
        }
    });
  });
}
```

This is the jQuery and AJAX call

```
<?php
 require_once "cdbconnect.php";

$taskTitle = $_POST['title'];
$taskDescription = $_POST['description'];
$memberName = $_POST['member'];
$groupName = "test";
$status = $_POST['status'];


 $query = "INSERT INTO task_tbl (Task_title, Task_description, Member_Name, Group_Name, Status) values('$taskTitle', '$taskDescription', '$memberName', '$groupName', '$status')";
 $result = $conn -> query($query);
 if(!$result)
   {
     $conn -> error;
   }

 mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This Is the PHP file. I always receive the failure alert as the data is not submitted to the table.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct? You can debug what is happening with the developer tools of your browser (F12 in Chrome & Firefox).

Comment: Just FYI, the link should be relative to the page, not the JS. And the above PHP code always returns HTTP 200, so it will never go to the `error` function, even if there's an error.

Comment: @Pharaoh Thank you for pointing that out. Yes it is now fixed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Suggestion, make the URL relative from the document root instead, like: `/path/to/file.php` (note the initial slash).

Comment: Consider using PDO or MySqlI

Answer (score 0):

A failing ajax request does not mean there is a logical error in your php script, but rather that the request could not be executed in the first place. Think "Server could not be reached", so your php code wasn't even executed.
Possible reasons are:

- Network problems
- Wrong url

In your case the url looks suspicious...